# vue.js data not updating when incremented

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have an object containing an array, which gets incremented after some amount of logic has completed.

Vue.js doesn't seem to be capturing this increment and displaying it to the view.

HTML:

```
<div id="demo">
  <p>{{points}}</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function Board()
{ 
  this.team1 = {pointsMade:[0]};
}

var newBoard = new Board();

newBoard.team1.pointsMade[0]++


new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    points: newBoard.team1.pointsMade
  }
})

setTimeout(newBoard.team1.pointsMade[0]++,1000)
```

I have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GerardSimpson/vjvMp/1020/) that outlines the problem.

You can see that after `setTimeout(newBoard.team1.pointsMade[0]++,1000)` runs, the value should be '2', but is only displayed at '1'. What am I missing here?

Comment: This is directly explained in the documentation https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: @AndyRay Great, I"m quite new to Vue.js however and am confused by the documentation, how would you go about implementing a solution to my described issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define

```
  data: {
    points: newBoard.team1.pointsMade[0]
  }
```

the `points` variable is just assigned current value of `newBoard.team1.pointsMade[0]`, which is `1` at this moment. There is no magic here. JS primitives works by value, not by references.

So, after updating the `newBoard.team1.pointsMade[0]` variable, the `point` variable is not updating of course.

To make this work, use object instead of primitive value. Objects work by reference in JS.

From [Properties and Methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Properties-and-Methods) example:

```
var data = { a: 1 }
var vm = new Vue({
  data: data
})
vm.a === data.a // -> true
// setting the property also affects original data
vm.a = 2
data.a // -> 2
// ... and vice-versa
data.a = 3
vm.a // -> 3
```

**edit**

There is another [caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) here:

Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect when you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`. So, use `Vue.set(newBoard.team1.pointsMade, 0, newBoard.team1.pointsMade[0] + 1);`.

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjvMp/1021/).

Comment: What if I were to set the view data to `newBoard.team1.pointsMade` instead of `newBoard.team1.pointsMade[0]`. Doesn't that set it to a reference type? I will edit my question to reflect this

Comment: Yes, sorry, there is another [caveat](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) here: Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect when you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`. So, use `Vue.set(newBoard.team1.pointsMade, 0, newBoard.team1.pointsMade[0] + 1);`.